# Query para obter soma 1024 em no máximo 3 transações

Tags: mysql

Eu quero exibir os nomes das pessoas (`recipient`) que receberam ao menos `1024` em no máximo 3 transações.

Aqui a tabela **"transfers"**:

```
   sender     | recipient  | date       | amount
  ------------+------------+------------+--------
   Smith      | Williams   | 2000-01-01 | 200
   Smith      | Taylor     | 2002-09-27 | 1024
   Smith      | Johnson    | 2005-06-26 | 512
   Williams   | Johnson    | 2010-12-17 | 100
   Williams   | Johnson    | 2004-03-22 | 10
   Brown      | Johnson    | 2013-03-20 | 500
   Johnson    | Williams   | 2007-06-02 | 400
   Johnson    | Williams   | 2005-06-26 | 400
   Johnson    | Williams   | 2005-06-26 | 200
```

Resposta:
Johnson e Taylor.

Como fazer essa query?

Comment: Como é definida uma transação?

Comment: Tem como colocar os inserts? precisa somar o valor, contar (transações) e acredito que usar um having

Comment: Dica , pesquise pelo use de GROUP BY e de HAVING https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: O Johnson recebeu mais de 1024 só que em 4 transações .... ta certo isso? então o unico que entra aí no critério é o Taylor

Comment: isso faz parte de um teste para uma empresa. eu teria que construir a query usando somente sql. Banco de dados mysqli.

Comment: **Nota:** mysqli não é banco de dados, é API, o banco é mysql.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vc está correto. Eu escrevi uma coisa pensando eu outra.

Comment: Creio que dê para fazer com uma CTE recursiva limitada a profundidade 3... Só uns bons minutos enquanto escrevo a consulta no celular

Comment: @rray, 512, 500 e 100. Essas são as transações do Johnson

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado o Johnson tem quatro transações, não três, 512, 100, >>10<<, 500.

Comment: @Inkeliz Mas com três dessas quatro ele consegue somar. Essa é a questão

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Uma maneira de organizar o problema é começar pelos valores maiores. Se os três primeiros valores não atenderem a condição pedida, com certeza valores menores também não vão atender.

### Organizando os dados

Dividindo o problema em partes, podemos obter os valores e a numeração de linhas usando variáveis do MySQL:

```
SET @cur_rec = "", @cur_line = NULL;

SELECT
  @cur_line := IF(@cur_rec = recipient, @cur_line + 1, 1) AS line,
  @cur_rec := recipient AS recipient,
  amount
FROM
  transactions
ORDER BY
  recipient,
  amount DESC
```

E o resultado é esse:

> ```
> line   recipient      amount
>    1   Johnson           512
>    2   Johnson           500
>    3   Johnson           100
>    4   Johnson            10
>    1   Taylor           1024
>    1   Williams          400
>    2   Williams          400
>    3   Williams          200
>    4   Williams          200
> ```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef612/1)**.

### Obtendo a resposta

Tendo os dados organizados, e sabendo que só atendem à condição propostas as somas cujo valor for `>= 1024` considerando `line <= 3`, podemos usar o SQL anterior como *subquery*:

```
SET @cur_rec = "", @cur_line = NULL;

SELECT
  recipient,
  SUM( amount ) AS total
FROM (
    ---- Aqui é exatamente a query do passo anterior ----
    SELECT
      @cur_line := IF(@cur_rec = recipient, @cur_line + 1, 1) AS line,
      @cur_rec := recipient AS recipient,
      amount
    FROM
      transactions
    ORDER BY
      recipient,
      amount DESC
    -----------------------------------------------------
  ) AS org
WHERE
  line < 4
GROUP BY
  recipient
HAVING
  total >= 1024
```

Resultado:

> ```
>    recipient       total
>    Johnson          1112
>    Taylor           1024
> ```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef612/2)**.

Answer (score 6):

Eu preciso que todas as linhas da tabela sejam numeradas unicamente para essa solução. Qualquer coisa, é trivial gerar uma tabela cópia de `transfers` com id autogerado. A essa coluna numerada unicamente estou dando o nome de `rowid`.

CTE é um conceito sql99 que, nas minhas leituras, funciona no MySQL 8 (em 2016 tava em desenvolvimento; vide [postagem no blog do MySQL](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/)) e [funciona no MariaDB 10.2.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/with/)

```
WITH RECURSIVE SOMA AS (
    SELECT
        RECIPIENT,
        ROWID as MAX_ROWID,
        1 as LEVEL, -- quantas transações diferentes já foram somadas, no caso aqui só a primeira de uma série de transações 
        ANOUNT as TOTAL
     FROM TRANSFERS
     UNION ALL -- daqui, vou para a parte recursiva
    SELECT
         S.RECIPIENT,
         T.ROWID as MAX_ROWID,
          LEVEL + 1 as LEVEL, -- acumulei mais uma transação na minha soma
          S.TOTAL + T.AMOUNT as TOTAL
     FROM
         SOMA S INNER JOIN TRANSFERS T
              ON (
                  T.RECIPIENT= S.RECIPIENT-- só faço a soma para o mesmo destinatário 
                   AND T.ROWID > S.MAX_ROWID -- garantia de que a soma não ocorrerá duas vezes na mesma linha
               )
    WHERE
          S.LEVEL <= 2 -- não precisamos somar mais do que 3 transações 
)
SELECT
    RECIPIENT,
    TOTAL,
     LEVEL
FROM SOMA
WHERE SOMA >= 1024
     AND LEVEL <= 3 -- checagem extra redundante, mas para deixar explícito que foram 3 transações ou menos
```

Para versões anteriores do MySQL, você pode [emular uma CTE recursiva com procedures](http://guilhembichot.blogspot.com.br/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html?m=1)

Answer (score 1):

Como dito pelo [@Motta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193752/como-fazer-essa-query/193849#comment399721_193752), utilize o `HAVING COUNT(recipient) <= 3 AND SUM(amount) >= 1024`, isso irá fazer com que obrigatoriamente tenha menos do que quatro transações/linhas e que a soma de todos os `amount` seja maior ou igual à 1024.

Por exemplo:

```
SELECT recipient 
FROM   transfers 
GROUP  BY recipient 
HAVING COUNT(recipient) <= 3 
       AND SUM(amount) >= 1024
```

---

Agora, no último comentário, esta query torna-se inutil. Se você deseja obter a soma de no máximo três elementos que resultem em maior ou igual a 1024, você pode pegar os maiores valores das três transações e em seguida verificar se a soma de todas as maiores transações são ou não maiores ou igual à 1024.

Logo:

```
SELECT recipient 
FROM transfers t 
GROUP BY t.recipient 
HAVING
(IFNULL(  
  (SELECT amount 
   FROM transfers s 
   WHERE s.recipient = t.recipient 
   ORDER BY amount DESC 
   LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0),
 0) + 
 IFNULL(  
  (SELECT amount 
   FROM transfers s 
   WHERE s.recipient = t.recipient 
   ORDER BY amount DESC 
   LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1),
 0) + 
 IFNULL(  
  (SELECT amount 
   FROM transfers s 
   WHERE s.recipient = t.recipient 
   ORDER BY amount DESC 
   LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2),
 0)) >= 1024
```

---

Uma outra tentativa, porém frustada foi utilizar:

```
group_concat(amount order by amount DESC)
```

Em seguida utilizar o `SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(...), '-', 3)`, assim obtendo os três últimos valores.

Porém o seu resultado é de, por exemplo:

```
512,500,100
```

Se houver alguma função que consiga quebrar o `,` e soma-los seria uma solução.

Comment: Não retorna o Johnson