# Testes de hipóteses com C# - Junção (soma) de valores para encontrar resultado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Olá, pessoal.

Preciso resolver o seguinte problema utilizando C# (ASP .NET MVC):

Possuo uma tabela no banco de dados que contém ID e Valor (decimal) como abaixo:

id: 1 | valor: 100,00
id: 2 | valor: 200,00
id: 3 | valor: 300,00
id: 4 | valor: 400,00
id: 5 | valor: 500,00

O resultado que desejo encontrar realizando a combinação dos valores é 1000,00.

Ou seja, eu teria o seguinte:
**Hipótese 1:** Somar os valores do id 1, 2, 3, 4 totalizando os 1000,00.
**Hipótese 2:** Somar os valores do id 1, 4, 5 totalizando os 1000,00.
**Hipótese 3:** Somar os valores do id 2, 3, 5 totalizando os 1000,00.

Como resultado final, exibirei as 3 hipóteses para o usuário para que ele escolha a que desejar.

Consegui resolver esse problema utilizando o [Solver](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Definir-e-resolver-um-problema-usando-o-Solver-9ed03c9f-7caf-4d99-bb6d-078f96d1652c), no Excel.

Alguém consegue dar uma luz para alcançar este resultado ou já enfrentou este tipo de problema?

Comment: bom o solver do excel utiliza alguns algoritmos como: LP Simplex, Gradação Reduzida Generalizada (GRG) Não Linear, e Evolucionário. Existem vários métodos de atacar esse problema mas n sei se é possível chegar a um algoritmo ótimo para este problema pois me parece muito ser um NP-completo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar recursão para isso.

Para esse exemplo, faremos um `for` entre todos os valores do banco. Em cada laço, tentamos verificar se existe uma possibilidade, ou seja, iremos buscar todas as possibilidades possíveis para verificar se alguma se encaixa para obter o valor solicitado.

Para cada laço iremos verificar os números abaixo do atual, ou seja, se o `i = 2`, nós iremos comparar somente os valores 100 e 200. A cada laço o valor de `i` será incrementado, garantindo assim que no último todos os valores sejam comparados.

Caso começarmos o primeiro laço com o valor de 100 (id 1). Subtraímos esse valor do total e verificamos a diferença. Caso seja o valor, retornamos ele. Caso ainda tenha um "resto", vamos atrás dos próximos valores para comprar o montante.

Para cada "nível de recursividade", o valor buscado será o resto para completar o montante, ou seja, se você começou com 1000 e subtraiu 200, você precisa buscar os 800 que faltam em algum lugar. Se não tiver um número que atenda essa premissa, iremos ir para o "próximo nível" e assim por diante.

Veja abaixo como ficaria [uma adaptação desta resposta para](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10739219/4843158) o seu exemplo:

```
var listaValores = new List<Dados>()
{
    new Dados { Id = 1, Valor = 100.00M},
    new Dados { Id = 2, Valor = 200.00M},
    new Dados { Id = 3, Valor = 300.00M},
    new Dados { Id = 4, Valor = 400.00M},
    new Dados { Id = 5, Valor = 500.00M}
};

public static IEnumerable<string> OterCombinacoes(List<Dados> dados, decimal sum, string values)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dados.Count; i++)
    {
        decimal resto = sum - dados[i].Valor;
        string vals = dados[i].Id + "," + values;
        if (resto == 0)
        {
            yield return vals;
        }
        else
        {
            List<Dados> dadosPossiveis = dados.Take(i).Where(n => n.Valor <= sum).ToList();
            if (dadosPossiveis.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string s in OterCombinacoes(dadosPossiveis, resto, vals))
                {
                    yield return s;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> O `originalValue` eu adicionei apenas para facilitar a persistência do valor buscado (1000). Para o seu caso, ele não é necessário.

[Veja funcionando no DotNetFiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fSLO3S)

Referências:

- [Efficient algorithm to find a combination, which summation is equal to a known number, in a set of number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10738926/4843158)
- [Algorithm to find which numbers from a list of size n sum to another number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/83547/4843158)
- [Finding ways to achieve a target sum using recursion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/122049)

Dicas de leitura:

- [Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)
- [Bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: Eu me lembrei de uma solução parecida com essa, para SQL: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193833/64969 ; mesmo conceito de busca recursiva no conjunto =D ; no meu caso, havia uma limitação máxima no tamanho do subconjunto, então isso ajudava a diminuir os níveis de recursão

Answer (score 4):

Se for possível ordenar os elementos dá para otimizar a busca de combinações.

Vou assumir que seja possível, e que os elementos sejam ordenados em ordem crescente, como mostra a figura.

[image: Elementos ordenados]

Os elementos maiores que 500 são laranja e os menores azuis. Na combinação, só pode haver 1 elemento laranja (para a soma ser < 1000).

### Buscas otimizadas

Existem vários algoritmos otimizados para busca em um conjunto ordenado. Uma bem fácil é a **busca binária**. Entretanto, se a distribuição dos valores dentro do conjunto for conhecida, podemos melhorar isso chutando uma posição onde é mais provável de achar o elemento fazendo uma **regressão**.

**Regressão:** para achar o valor 250, poderiamos chutar a posição 5 fazendo uma [regressão linear](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regress%C3%A3o_linear), como apresentado a seguir:

```
(val-min)/(max-min)*tam = 5,26
val = 250  // valor buscado
min = 50   // menor valor
max = 1000 // maior valor
tam = 25   // contagem de elementos
```

[image: Regressão linear]

E o que encontramos é 200 lá nessa posição... mesmo porque 250 não é um elemento da lista, mas veja como foi próximo.

Se a distribuição fosse outra, bastaria fazer uma regressão apropriada para achar o lugar mais provável. Qualquer otimização vai depender do conjunto de dados, não existe uma solução para todos os problemas.

**Busca binária:** possui ordem de log(n), onde n é a quantidade de elementos no conjunto. Note que para cada elemento, achar um menor que ele significa procurar apenas dentre os elementos que estão antes dele.

Quando a busca binária não acha nada, possui a vantagem de já apontar para o valor mais próximo.

[Busca binária na wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesquisa_bin%C3%A1ria)

O .Net já fornece implementações nativas, isso pode ser uma vantagem:

- [Array.BinarySearch(T[], T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/2cy9f6wb(v=vs.110).aspx)

  ```
  var array = new[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 11, };
  var idx1 = Array.BinarySearch(array, 4); // retorna -3 ... ~(-3) = 2 é a posição onde deveria estar
  var idx2 = Array.BinarySearch(array, 7); // retorna 3 ... achou!
  ```
- [List.BinarySearch(T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx)

### Fazendo as combinações

Podemos usar recursão para achar as combinações, mas como a outra resposta já dá essa solução, vou mostrar uma forma com pilhas. Além disso, o tamanho da pilha pode ser predefinida: é a quantidade dos menores elementos que temos que somar para quase passar de 1000.

[image: maior soma abaixo de 1000 = 7 menores]

<sup>maior soma abaixo de 1000 = 7 menores, dando 930...
 a pilha terá 7 elementos então</sup>

Começamos varrendo a lista do maior valor para o menor valor. Vou escrever um passo-a-passo das operações para dar uma noção de como vai ficar o algoritmo final.

**Elemento 1000:** Colocamos o primeiro valor na pilha e verificamos a soma. O primeiro é 1000, e já pode ser retornado logo de cara... removemos ele e adicionamos o próximo.

**Elemento 980:** Já dá pra sacar de cara que não vai formar nenhuma combinação, pois não há um valor 20. A busca binária iria apontar o índice `0`, e a regressão linear retornaria `-0,7`, ou seja, tá fora da lista.

**Elemento 900:** Vamos por 900 na pilha. Temos que buscar agora um valor igual a 100. Usando a regressão vou obter `1,3`. Na posição 1, acho 60. Na próxima acho 100... adiciono o 100 na pilha, e retorno a combinação. Removo o 100 da pilha.

Só que pode ser que exista uma combinação com 3 elementos. Vou descer 1 posição, a que tem o 60 e adicionar ele na pilha. Falta 40 pra dar 100, mas veja bem, o menor valor é 50, então não haverá combinações com 60, nem com nada menor que ele. Tiro ele da pilha.

Tiro o 900 da pilha.

**Elemento 880:** Vamos por o 880 na pilha. Falta 120 pra 1000. Uma busca rápida já indica o 120. Depois dessa combinação, temos que tentar o 100, coloco ele na pilha. Falta 20... já era. Tento o próximo, 60, com 880 falta 60 pra 1000. Acho o 50, ponho no pilha também. Agora falta 10, mas não existe 10... vou tirando tudo da pilha.

Já deu pra notar o que está acontecendo por alto...

### Programa

Então vamos à implementação.

Esse é um programa console, que usa os dados dos gráficos acima, e acha as combinações que somam 1000, usando pilhas. É possível escolher qual algoritmo de busca usar... o programa irá perguntar.

Depois de rodar ele mostra as combinações, e mostra o tempo que levou.
Aqui no meu computador não notei grande diferença entre usar um método de busca ou outro, para um conjunto de dados aleatório pequeno (até 100 elementos).

Quando aumentei para 230 elementos entretanto a busca com regressão ficou mais rápida:

- busca com regressão:

  ```
  Elementos no array: 238
  Tempo total: 25892,236ms
  Combinações: 20206396
  ```
- busca binária

  ```
  Elementos no array: 238
  Tempo total: 31417,774ms
  Combinações: 20205573
  ```

**Código**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace CombArraySoma
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.WriteLine("R = usar busca com regressão");
                Console.WriteLine("B = usar busca binária");
                Console.WriteLine("Outra tecla = sair do programa");
                var key = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine();
                var tipoBusca = key.KeyChar == 'r' ? (Busca)BuscaComRegressao
                    : key.KeyChar == 'b' ? (Busca)BuscaBinaria :
                        null;

                if (tipoBusca == null) return;

                var array = new[]
                {
                    50, 60, 100, 120, 180, 200, 220, 320, 360, 420, 460, 480, 500, 520, 580, 640, 660, 700, 780, 800, 860,
                    880, 900, 980, 1000
                };
                //var rand = new Random();
                //array = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(x => (int)(rand.NextDouble() * 1000) + 1)
                //    .Where(x => x >= 50 && x <= 1000)
                //    .Select(x => x - (x % 10))
                //    .Distinct()
                //    .OrderBy(x => x)
                //    .ToArray();

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine($"Elementos no array: {array.Length}");
                Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(",", array)}]");

                const int objetivo = 1000;

                int soma = 0;

                // a pilha pode ser pré-alocada
                int tampilha;
                for (tampilha = 0; tampilha < array.Length; tampilha++)
                {
                    soma += array[tampilha];
                    if (soma > objetivo)
                        break;
                }

                var pilha = new Stack<int>(tampilha);

                var startTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

                var combos = new List<int[]>(array.Length * array.Length);
                soma = 0;
                var idx = array.Length - 1;
                pilha.Push(idx);
                soma += array[idx];
                while (pilha.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (soma == objetivo)
                    {
                        combos.Add(pilha.Reverse().ToArray());
                        while (pilha.Count > 0)
                        {
                            idx = pilha.Pop();
                            soma -= array[idx];
                            idx--;
                            if (idx >= 0)
                            {
                                pilha.Push(idx);
                                soma += array[idx];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (soma < objetivo)
                    {
                        var top = pilha.Peek() - 1;
                        idx = tipoBusca(array, objetivo - soma, 0, top);
                        if (idx < 0) idx = ~idx - 1;
                        if (idx >= 0 && idx <= top && array[idx] + soma <= objetivo)
                        {
                            pilha.Push(idx);
                            soma += array[idx];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            while (pilha.Count > 0)
                            {
                                idx = pilha.Pop();
                                soma -= array[idx];
                                idx--;
                                if (idx >= 0)
                                {
                                    pilha.Push(idx);
                                    soma += array[idx];
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                var endTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

                foreach (var combo in combos.Take(20))
                {
                    for (int it = 0; it < combo.Length; it++)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                        if (it > 0)
                            Console.Write($" + ");
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                        Console.Write($" [");
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        Console.Write(combo[it]);
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                        Console.Write($"]");
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                        Console.Write(array[combo[it]]);
                    }
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                    Console.Write($" = ");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.Write($"{combo.Select(i => array[i]).Sum()}");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                if (combos.Skip(20).Any())
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine($"...");
                }

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine($"Tempo total: {(endTime - startTime) * 1000.0 / Stopwatch.Frequency:F3}ms");

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine($"Combinações: {combos.Count}");
            }
        }

        private static int BuscaBinaria(int[] array, int valor, int a, int b)
        {
            if (b - a + 1 < 0) return ~a;
            return Array.BinarySearch(array, a, b - a + 1, valor);
        }

        public static int BuscaComRegressao(int[] array, int valor, int a, int b)
        {
            if (b < a) return ~a;

            var x = a == b ? a : (valor - array[a]) * (b - a) / (array[b] - array[a]);
            if (x > b) return ~(b + 1);
            if (x < a) return ~a;

            // a regressão se beneficia da localidade de cache do processador
            // com as varreduras sequenciais abaixo
            while (array[x] > valor)
            {
                if (x == a) return ~a;
                x--;
            }
            while (array[x] < valor)
            {
                x++;
                if (x > b) return ~(b + 1);
            }
            return array[x] == valor ? x : ~x;
        }

        delegate int Busca(int[] array, int valor, int a, int b);
    }
}
```

A saída é a seguinte:

[image: Saída do programa]

### Outras otimizações

Algoritmos como esse pode se beneficiar de algumas outras otimizações como memoização e localidade de cache do processador.

**Memoização:** consta em armazenar num dicionário os resultados intermediários que podem ser requisitados mais de uma vez. Por exemplo, se o algoritmo precisa saber várias vezes quais são as combinações que geram 200, então é interessante colocar essas combinações num dicionário das combinações de 200. Assim, durante o processo de achar as combinações que dão 1000, quando quisermos o valor 200 já sabemos quais elas são.

A eficiência disso depende muito do conjunto de dados com o qual se está trabalhando, e além disso pode acabar consumindo bastante memória.

**Localidade de cache:** a busca por regressão usa essa propriedade, pois depois de achar a posição mais provável, ele tem que varrer os elementos em volta daquela posição para achar a posição exata. Acontece que quando o processador carrega uma posição de memória os elementos no entorno são carregados junto, o que faz o algoritmo ser bem eficiente mesmo que não acerte 100%.

O mesmo não se pode dizer da busca binária por exemplo, pois no início da busca acessa posições de memória que podem estar bem distantes umas das outras. Apesar disso, a busca binária pode ser considerada um algoritmo **["cache oblivious"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-oblivious_algorithm)**, ou seja, ele subdivide o problema de forma que eventualmente o conjunto de dados do problema vai caber na cache, sem importar a hierarquia de cache sendo usada.

O melhor a fazer é verificar os seus dados, e usar o algoritmo que mais se adeque... preferencialmente fazendo alguns testes de performance.

### P.S.

- Código que eu fiz para gerar o gráfico de barras para esta resposta

```js
/*/

var vals = [
  [1000, 980, 900, 880, 860, 800, 780, 700, 660, 640, 580, 520, 500, 480, 460, 420, 360, 320, 220, 200, 180, 120, 100, 60, 50],
  [1000, 900, 840, 820, 800, 760, 700, 660, 640, 600, 560, 540, 520, 500, 480, 460, 440, 400, 300, 200, 180, 140, 80, 60, 50],
  [1000, 860, 800, 780, 740, 720, 640, 600, 560, 540, 500, 480, 440, 420, 400, 360, 340, 320, 300, 280, 240, 180, 120, 60, 50]
  ]

vals.map(createCanvas)
/*/
var h = 1000
var ch = 100
for(var xx=0;xx<10000;xx++) {
  vals = randomArray(25, h)
  vals.sort((x,y)=>y-x)
  vals[0] = 1000
  vals[vals.length-1] = 50
  vals[5]=800
  vals[10]=500
  vals.sort((x,y)=>y-x)
  //console.log(xx)
  var it = 1
  for (; it < vals.length; it++)
    if (vals[it] == vals[it-1]) break
  if (it >= vals.length && vals[vals.length-1]>=50) break
}
createCanvas(vals)
//console.log(vals)
/**/

function createCanvas(vals) {
  // var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
  var myCanvas = document.createElement("canvas")
  document.body.appendChild(myCanvas)
  
  myCanvas.width = 550
  myCanvas.height = 170
  myCanvas.style.width = myCanvas.width+"px"
  myCanvas.style.height = myCanvas.height+"px"
  
  var h = 1000
  var ch = 100
  //myCanvas.width = 550
  //myCanvas.height = ch + 100

  var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d")
  //ctx.translate(10, 10);

  vals.sort((x,y)=>x-y)
  var w = Math.floor(myCanvas.width / vals.length)
  for (var it = 0; it < vals.length; it++) {
    var v = vals[it]
    var r = v > h/2 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
    var g = v > h/2 ? mapp(v,h/2,h,0.9,0.3,2) : mapp(v,0,h/2,0.1,0.8,2);
    var b = v > h/2 ? 0.0 : mapp(v,0,h/2,0.3,1,0.3);
    var barH = ch*vals[it]/h
    drawBar(ctx, it*w+1, ch - barH, w - 2, barH, rgb(r,g,b))
    drawText(ctx, it, v, it*w + 3, ch+10, -Math.PI*80/180)
  }

  drawLine(ctx, 0,ch,550,ch,"#000000");
}

function drawLine(ctx, startX, startY, endX, endY,color){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY+0.5);
    ctx.lineTo(endX, endY+0.5);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawBar(ctx, upperLeftCornerX, upperLeftCornerY, width, height,color){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle=color;
    ctx.fillRect(upperLeftCornerX,upperLeftCornerY,width,height);
    ctx.restore();
}

function randomArray(length, max) {
    return Array.apply(null, Array(length)).map(function() {
        var r = Math.random()//Math.pow(Math.random()/2,Math.random())
        r += 0.01
        r = Math.floor(mapp(r,0,1,0,max,1))
        r = Math.floor(r/20)*20
        return r;
    });
}

function rgb(r,g,b) { return '#'+[r,g,b].map(function(d){return (d>=1?255:d<0?0:Math.floor(d*256)).toString(16).padStart(2, '0')}).join("")
}

function mapp(x,a,b,c,d,p) { return Math.pow((x-a)/(b-a),p)*(d-c)+c }

function drawText(ctx, it, v, x, y, angle) {
  var text = "["+it+"] "+v.toString()
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(-angle);
  ctx.textAlign = "left";
  ctx.font = ctx.font.replace(/\d+px/, "13px");
  var idx = "["+it+"]: "
  var sz = ctx.measureText(idx);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'gray';
  ctx.fillText(idx, 0, 0);
  ctx.fillStyle = v > 500 ? 'red' : 'blue';
  ctx.fillText(v.toString(), sz.width, 0);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

- [Inspiração para o gráfico que eu fiz, e além disso eles também possuem algo sobre um problema parecido](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/icon/oddsends/bpack/bpack.htm) - [problema de empacotamento (wikipedia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_do_empacotamento)