# MySQL Query com recursividade em N níveis

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho a seguinte query

```
    select  id,
        nome,
        user_id
from    (select * from users
         order by user_id, id) users,
        (select @pv := '2') initialisation
where   find_in_set(user_id, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)
union
select  id,
        nome,
        user_id
from users where id = 2
```

E aqui estão alguns valores fake para essa tabela.

```
ID  NAME        USER_ID
1   Main User   0
2   User A      1
3   User B      1
4   User C      2
5   User D      2
6   User E      2
7   User F      4
8   User G      4
9   User H      1
10  User I      1
11  User J      2
```

A query funciona, mas eu preciso que os resultados estejam aninhados e ordenados pelo nível do usuário.

No exemplo da query, eu passei o ID 2, então o resultado deveria vir assim:

```
2. User A
 ___ 4. User C
    ___ 7. User F
    ___ 8. User G
 ___ 5. User D
 ___ 6. User E
 ___ 11. User J
```

Pode ser com os __ no resultado, não tem problema. O importante é ter esse esquema de árvore.

Obrigado.

Comment: Qual a versão do MYSQL ?

Comment: Relevante: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193833/64969

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No mysql, em versões >= 8, você pode utilizar uma CTE (Common Table Expressions), que pode ser recursiva. Fiz um exemplo:

```
with recursive aux (id , nome , user_id , i  , seq ) as
(
    select
    id, 
    name,
    coalesce(user_id,0) as user_id,
    CAST('' AS CHAR(100)) as i,
    cast(LPAD(id,3,'0') as char(100)) as seq
    from users where id = 2

UNION ALL

    select
    c.id, 
    c.name,
    c.user_id,
    concat(x.i , '  '),
    concat(x.seq , '.',LPAD(c.id,3,'0')) as seq
    from users c
INNER JOIN aux x ON c.user_id = x.id
)

select 
x.id,
x.nome,
x.user_id as pai,
concat(x.i,'__ ',x.id,'. ', x.nome) as raiz,
x.seq
from aux x order by seq;
```

Coloquei no [Db-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2yAmVjKiJ6EY9DRMaD4RuD/2) (SQLFiddle não suporta)

> Resultado:

[image: Resultado DBFiddle]

Utilizando o Id 2, como informado no exemplo:

[image: Resultado DBFiddle]

ps. Exibi também o campo `seq` que utilizo pra ordenar os registros.

Como Jefferson Quesado mencionou nos comentários, ele tem uma resposta [AQUI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193833/69359) que faz um exemplo de outra situação semelhante, além de direcionar para o [blog do MySql](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/) que fala sobre as CTE (Common Table Expressions)

Answer (score 1):

Isso não aparecerá dessa forma no mysql só em outra linguagem pois exige indentação tal como o html oferece as listas

```
function dba_buscaproximo($id_pai = null) {
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM `ingredientes`
            WHERE id_pai = {$id_pai} order by nome";
    $consulta = mysql_query($sql);
    return $consulta;
}

function dba_buscapai($id_filho = null) {
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM `ingredientes`
            WHERE id_ingrediente = {$id_filho} order by nome";

    $consulta = mysql_query($sql);
    return $consulta;
}

<html>
 <ul>    
        <?php
        buscafilho();

        ?>
    </ul>

</html>
```

Essa é uma chamada recursiva onde eu busco o próximo filho enquanto ainda existirem filhos dentro desse pai é um grande loop que deve ser resolvido em uma liguagem de programação e não no mysql.

Codigo retirado do meu TCC =D

```
function buscafilho($id_pai = 0) { 

    $consulta = dba_buscaproximo($id_pai);

    if (mysql_num_rows($consulta) > 0) {
        if ($id_pai != 0) {
            echo "<ul>";
        }
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {

            echo '<li>';

            echo $row["nome"];
            buscafilho($row['id_ingrediente']);

            echo '</li>';

        }
        if ($id_pai != 0) {
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O uso de query e sub query ao invés de select e sub select aparentemente não é tão atraente e nem é a melhor performance, correto?

Comment: Se notares o que eu usei foi uma recursão, ou seja enquanto tiver filhos constroi, porem sub query para este problema especifico fica sem sentido por que eu preciso construir a hierarquia dos itens dentro da li ou seja com uma subquery dentro de uma query eu não tenho como fazer esta construção dos itens pores este motivo para está situação eu contrui essa recursão.

Comment: @EliseuB. se notares  não é query e sub query é query + query baseado em uma recursão de construção pode ser usado para menus.
Reviver um tópico de 2018 vale a pena mesmo?

Comment: Sim, vale a pena se está na SOpt, e se está por aqui é debatível, qualidade acima de tudo na comunidade, até fiz testes por aqui e teve uma ótima performance com até 100 mil registros que tenho em uma base de dados para testes. Abraço