# RETORNAR A SOMA DE NO MAXIMO 3 VALORES EM SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sum, select-limit

tenho uma table e preciso retornar o seguinte:
verificar com base na coluna recipient, somar as 3 maiores amount daquele recipient, trazer na query apenas se a soma das 3 maiores forem >= 1024:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSFERS(
SENDER VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
RECIPIENT VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
DATA DATE NOT NULL,
AMOUNT INTEGER NOT NULL);


INSERT INTO TRANSFERS VALUES ('Smith', 'Williams', '01/01/2000', 200);
INSERT INTO TRANSFERS VALUES ('Smith', 'Taylor', '27/09/2002', 1024);
INSERT INTO TRANSFERS VALUES ('Smith', 'JOHNSON', '26/06/2005', 512);
INSERT INTO TRANSFERS VALUES ('Williams', 'JOHNSON', '17/12/2010', 100);
INSERT INTO TRANSFERS VALUES ('Williams', 'JOHNSON', '22/03/2004', 10);
INSERT INTO TRANSFERS VALUES ('Brown', 'JOHNSON', '20/03/2013', 500);
INSERT INTO TRANSFERS VALUES ('JOHNSON', 'Williams', '02/06/2007', 400);
INSERT INTO TRANSFERS VALUES ('JOHNSON', 'Williams', '26/06/2005', 400);
INSERT INTO TRANSFERS VALUES ('JOHNSON', 'Williams', '26/06/2005', 200);
```

nesse cenário o SELECT deve trazer os nomes de Taylor e JHONSON pois, Taylor em uma transferencia ele já tem o valor de 1024, já Jhonson a soma das 3 maiores dele como Recipient é: 512, 500 e 100 = 1112;

consegui apenas trazer o taylor:

```
SELECT T.RECIPIENT AS NOME
FROM TRANSFERS T
WHERE T.AMOUNT >= 1024;
```

obrigado!

Comment: É esse mesmo problema, mesmo enunciado, segue solução com MySQL (ou outros DBs que aceitem variáveis): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193752/

Comment: Veja como ficou: https://prnt.sc/jzz21c Se não tivesse apagado eu ja estava respondendo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma outra abordagem, utilizando [row_number()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html):

```
select 
    x.recipient,
    sum(x.amount) as soma
from 
    (select
         t.recipient,
         t.amount,
         row_number() over (partition by recipient order by amount desc) as i
     from transfers t) x
where x.i <=3
group by x.recipient
having sum(x.amount) >= 1024;
```

Quanto ao desempenho, não sei qual seria melhor, só realizando um teste.

Comment: +1 pela excelente resposta.

Comment: já removi o comentário, aguardar pra ele acertar... obrigado! vc sempre fera nas respostas com postgres =]

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma função `PL/PgSQL` para realizar esse cálculo, veja só:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fc_obter_top3()
RETURNS TABLE ( RECIPIENT  VARCHAR(200), AMOUNT BIGINT ) AS 
$$
DECLARE
   rec RECORD;
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN SELECT trsf.RECIPIENT FROM TRANSFERS AS trsf GROUP BY trsf.RECIPIENT
   LOOP
       RETURN QUERY SELECT
                      rec.RECIPIENT,
                      SUM(top.AMOUNT) 
                    FROM
                      (SELECT t.AMOUNT FROM TRANSFERS AS t WHERE t.RECIPIENT = rec.RECIPIENT ORDER BY t.AMOUNT DESC LIMIT 3) AS top
                    HAVING
                      SUM(top.AMOUNT) >= 1024;
   END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Testando:

```
SELECT * FROM fc_obter_top3();
```

Saída:

```
| recipient | amount |
|-----------|--------|
|   JOHNSON |   1112 |
|    Taylor |   1024 |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1d0fd/3)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  T.RECIPIENT AS NOME,
  SUM(T_TMP.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL
FROM TRANSFERS T
JOIN (SELECT TOP 3 T2.RECIPIENT, T2.AMOUNT FROM TRANSFERS T2 ORDER BY T2.AMOUNT DESC) AS T_TMP  ON T.RECIPIENT = T_TMP.RECIPIENT
GROUP BY T.RECIPIENT
HAVING SUM(T.AMOUNT) >= 1024;
```

Não é muito performático mas acredito que deve resolver o problema.

obs: **[nesse link](http://rextester.com/live/FDCN37515)** é possível testar a solução acima (*sql server*).

---

**editado**

para *postgresql* (também com um **[exemplo aqui](http://rextester.com/live/EZBE10572)**):

```
SELECT 
  T.RECIPIENT AS NOME,
  SUM(T_TMP.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL
FROM TRANSFERS T
JOIN (SELECT T2.RECIPIENT, T2.AMOUNT FROM TRANSFERS T2 ORDER BY T2.AMOUNT DESC LIMIT 3) AS T_TMP  ON T.RECIPIENT = T_TMP.RECIPIENT
GROUP BY T.RECIPIENT
HAVING SUM(T.AMOUNT) >= 1024;
```

Comment: ainda está dando erro, agora na linha onde vc colocou = SELECT TOP 3 T3.... erro de missing expression.

Comment: @EduardoRafaelMoraes alterei a consulta, veja se agora atende. Testei o o script em cima do que você postou na pergunta, aparentemente está ok

Comment: estou usando o postgre, provavelmente por isso, ele não está reconhecendo o TOP 3, está esperando um FROM depois do TOP

Comment: @EduardoRafaelMoraes, dá uma sacada com o novo ajuste. Também editei a pergunta pra adicionar a _tag_ do banco

Comment: Sua consulta está errada. O somatório esperado de `JOHNSON` é `1112`, sua consulta está retornando `4048`. Veja só no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8adf9/1)

Comment: obrigado linhares